# Jest mock method return specific result depending on input

Tags: javascript, jestjs

## tl;dr

I'm trying to mock `fs.readdirSync()` when the input is `X`.

---

So initially I mocked the method and added the desired output

```
fs.readdirSync = jest.fn();
fs.readdirSync.mockReturnValue(['my data here']);
```

Although now it is always using that output, but I only want it one time, and the others it should be the original method,
So AFAIU it is possible to mock the method and still have the original method has the default by doing

```
const originalReaddirSync = fs.readdirSync;
fs.readdirSync = jest.fn(path => originalReaddirSync(path));
fs.readdirSync.mockReturnValueOnce(['my data here']);
```

This almost does the expected work, but the call I want to override is the 2nd call.

**Q: Is there a way to say, if the `path` is `X` return `Y`?**

---

I come from PHP background and I'm trying to achive the following example with mockery

```
$mockedObject->shouldReceive('method')
    ->once()
    ->with('this argument')
    ->andReturn(['my data here']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mock the value once for each test case:

`index.ts`:

```
import fs from 'fs';

function readdirSync(path) {
  return fs.readdirSync(path);
}

export { readdirSync };
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```
import { readdirSync } from './';
import fs from 'fs';

fs.readdirSync = jest.fn();

describe('readdirSync', () => {
  it('t1', () => {
    (fs.readdirSync as jest.MockedFunction<any>).mockReturnValueOnce(['Y']);
    const actualValue = readdirSync('X');
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(['Y']);
    expect(fs.readdirSync).toBeCalledWith('X');
  });

  it('t2', () => {
    (fs.readdirSync as jest.MockedFunction<any>).mockReturnValueOnce(['Z']);
    const actualValue = readdirSync('T');
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(['Z']);
    expect(fs.readdirSync).toBeCalledWith('T');
  });
});
```

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/46911799/index.spec.ts
  readdirSync
    ✓ t1 (8ms)
    ✓ t2 (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.917s, estimated 5s
```

**UPDATE**

you can use `jest.fn().mockImplementation()` as well.

Unit test，

1. if the path is X return Y
2. if the path is T return Z

```
import { readdirSync } from './';
import fs from 'fs';

fs.readdirSync = jest.fn().mockImplementation(path => {
  switch (path) {
    case 'X':
      return ['Y'];
    case 'T':
      return ['Z'];
  }
});

describe('readdirSync', () => {
  it('t3', () => {
    const actualValue = readdirSync('X');
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(['Y']);
    expect(fs.readdirSync).toBeCalledWith('X');
  });

  it('t4', () => {
    const actualValue = readdirSync('T');
    expect(actualValue).toEqual(['Z']);
    expect(fs.readdirSync).toBeCalledWith('T');
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/46911799/index-2.spec.ts
  readdirSync
    ✓ t3 (5ms)
    ✓ t4 (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.345s
```

Comment: wow, you really went deep to find this old question, thank you very much for the answer... Still, it is a different way of working, and we can even say that it is a wrong one, that for JS it is much easier to mock it on the fly. This works but it isn't what I was looking for. I'll  but can't mark it as correct answer.

Comment: @mloureiro Update answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Shoot I was just making that answer, anyway, thank you very much, and I'll mark it as correct! ❤️